# Interval of Convergence for the Taylor Series of $f(x) = \frac{\ln x}{x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

So far, I have found that the Taylor series for $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ centered at $x=1$ is

$$f(x) = (x-1) - \frac{3(x-1)^2}{2} + \frac{11(x-1)^3}{6} - \cdots$$

However, I wanted to take it a step further and find the interval of convergence. From plugging in various numbers, I have come up with the interval $[0, 2]$. Would this interval be correct? Also, what would be the formal step to get to this solution?

Comment: It's $(0,2)$...

Comment: Whoops! Completely forgot about 2. Fixed.

Comment: Hint: show that $$ \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}H_kx^k $$ where $H_k$ are the [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We know the geometric series is
\begin{equation}
‎ 1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x}‎
‎\end{equation}‎
Which is converge for ‎$|x|<1$. With integration of both sides
‎\begin{equation}
‎ x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots+\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+\cdots=-\ln(1-x)~~~~;~~~~|x|<1‎
‎\end{equation}‎
multiplying two series concludes
‎\begin{equation}
‎ -\dfrac{\ln(1-x)}{1-x}=x+\frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{11}{6}x^3+\frac{25}{12}x^7+\cdots~~~~;~~~~|x|<1‎
‎\end{equation}‎
replace $1-x$ with $u$ gives us
‎\begin{equation}
‎ \dfrac{\ln u}{u}=(u-1)-\frac{3}{2}(x-1)^2+\frac{11}{6}(x-1)^3-\frac{25}{12}(x-1)^7+\cdots~~~~;~~~~0<u<2.
‎\end{equation}‎
shows convergence in $0<u<2$.

Comment: This shows convergence for $u$ in $(0,2)$. What is lacking is a proof of divergence for $u$ not in $(0,2)$ (if this is the result you are implying).